# create multiple jobs from similar assets with different partitions and schedules

Tags: dagster

I have a `assets.py` with the following:

```
from dagster import asset, job, Output

from my_modules import some_func


from ..partitions import daily_partitions_def, t1_daily_partitions_def

@asset(partitions_def=t1_daily_partitions_def)
def get_rfr_final_asset(context):
    dt = context.partition_key
    some_func(dt, provisonal=True)
    return True

@asset(partitions_def=daily_partitions_def)
def get_rfr_provisional_asset(context):
    dt = context.partition_key
    some_func(dt, provisonal=False)
    return True
```

In my main dagster file, how can I create two jobs, one with the first asset and a second with the second asset both on different schedules. If I use `load_assets_from_modules` it groups both assets together, I'd like a cleaner way to do this instead of having multiple files for each asset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```py
from assets import get_rfr_final_asset, get_rfr_provisional_asset

rfr_final_job = define_asset_job(
    "rfr_final_job", selection=[get_rfr_final_asset]
)
rfr_provisional_job = define_asset_job(
    "rfr_provisional_job", selection=[get_rfr_provisional_asset]
)
```